# PHP switch statement

Tags: php

I currently have a page called "user.php", where I have a HTML form that allows users to select from a list of nutrition-related information, and some PHP code that handles the input and eventually store them into a MySQL database:

```
 <form action="user.php" method="post">
   ......
 <select class="sel-dropdown" name="nutri-info">
        <option value="empty"></option>     
        <option value="<200">&lt;200 cal</option>
        <option value="200 - 399">200 - 399 cal</option>
        <option value="400 - 599">400 - 599 cal</option>
        <option value="600 - 799">600 - 799 cal</option>
        <option value="800 - 999">800 - 999 cal</option>
        <option value=">1000">&gt; 1000 cal</option>
</select> 
......
</form>
```

And the PHP at the top of the page is as follows. What I'm trying to do is to convert each range of calories into a number, and store that number into the database.

```
...
$nutrition = $_POST['nutri-info'];
switch($nutrition){
        case "<200 cal":
           $calories = 1;
           break;
        case "200 - 399 cal":
           $calories = 2;
           break;
        case "400 - 599 cal":
           $calories = 3;
           break;
        case "600 - 799 cal":
           $calories = 4;
           break;
        case "800 - 999 cal":
           $calories = 5;
           break;
        case ">1000 cal":
           $calories = 6;
           break;         
        default:
            $calories = 10;   
    }
```

But the problem is that, no matter which item I select in the HTML form, the result of $calories is always 10, the value of the default case. Any idea on what might gone wrong?

Comment: wouldnt it make more sense to use the number in the first place instead of switch/casing it like this?

Comment: Why you are checking "`<200 cal`", as your values don't contain 'cal' word, either add it in value in HTML `<option>` or remove it from `case`

Comment: @fittaoee please select the correct answer, so in future if somebody refers this thread can come to know what was the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value return in `$_POST['nutri-info']`  is like `200 - 399` and you are checking in switch case with `200 - 399 cal`.

Try to remove `cal` from switch case or add `cal` in option value

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why the value in $_POST['nutri-info'] will only contain ""200 - 399", but not "cal"?

Comment: $_POST['nutri-info'] return value of option and if value attribute not in option then it will return text of option.

Comment: So does it suggest that, if I add "cal" into the value="" attribute in <option>, then it will also be passed into the $_POST[] variable?

Comment: If you have value in option tag then it will return that as a submitting value otherwise it will return text inside option tag --> <option>text</option>

Answer (score 0):

The switch should include exactly the values you have set in the HTML select.

```
switch($nutrition){
        case "<200":
           $calories = 1;
           break;
        case "200 - 399":
           $calories = 2;
           break;
        case "400 - 599":
           $calories = 3;
           break;
        case "600 - 799":
           $calories = 4;
           break;
        case "800 - 999":
           $calories = 5;
           break;
        case ">1000":
           $calories = 6;
           break;         
        default:
            $calories = 10;   
}
```

Just remove the **cal** part

Answer (score 0):

change your options value to this

```
<option value="200 - 399 cal">200 - 399 cal</option>
<option value="400 - 599 cal">400 - 599 cal</option>
<option value="600 - 799 cal">600 - 799 cal</option>

...do like this
```

Beacuse form submiting the form element value

Answer (score 0):

It's great you learned how to correct the mistake with the `switch` statement..!

You may find it useful to learn one more thing: The `value` attributes of your options are for you, not for your user.  What I mean is, they don't see it, so you can put whatever you want in there.

So, rather than passing yourself a string description of the selection (*which requires you to 'figure out' the integer value using the switch*), just **simply pass yourself the integer as the value to begin with!**

So instead of:

```
<select class="sel-dropdown" name="nutri-info">
     <option value="empty"></option>     
     <option value="<200">&lt;200 cal</option>
     <option value="200 - 399">200 - 399 cal</option>
     <option value="400 - 599">400 - 599 cal</option>
     <option value="600 - 799">600 - 799 cal</option>
     <option value="800 - 999">800 - 999 cal</option>
     <option value=">1000">&gt; 1000 cal</option>
</select>
```

Do this:

```
<select class="sel-dropdown" name="nutri-info">
     <option value=""></option>     
     <option value="1">&lt;200 cal</option>
     <option value="2">200 - 399 cal</option>
     <option value="3">400 - 599 cal</option>
     <option value="4">600 - 799 cal</option>
     <option value="5">800 - 999 cal</option>
     <option value="6">&gt; 1000 cal</option>
</select>
```

Then you get exactly the value you want, without needing the switch at all:

```
$calories = $_POST['nutri-info'];

// The switch is no longer needed..!
//
// $nutrition = $_POST['nutri-info'];
// switch($nutrition){
//         case "<200 cal":
//            $calories = 1;
//            break;
//         case "200 - 399 cal":
//            $calories = 2;
//            break;
//         case "400 - 599 cal":
//            $calories = 3;
//            break;
//         case "600 - 799 cal":
//            $calories = 4;
//            break;
//         case "800 - 999 cal":
//            $calories = 5;
//            break;
//         case ">1000 cal":
//            $calories = 6;
//            break;         
//         default:
//             $calories = 10;   
//     }
```

The moral of the story is: set the `value` attributes so they are meaningful for YOU.  The user only sees what is in between the angled brackets:

`<option value="2">` **200 - 399 cal** `</option>`

So, that's all that has to be meaningful for them.

Comment: Ah yeah! Very clever! Didn't think about doing it this way. Thank you very much.